# Laravel not find item by id

Tags: php, laravel

I stuck in middle of something to delete a single item from `db`

```
$remove = Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->where('id', $request->id)->remove();
return response()->json($remove, 200);
```

It always return `false` but when I remove this-> `->where('id', $request->id)`, it work fine, also on this return false too:

```
Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->where('id', $request->id)->first();
```

but this return true:

```
Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->first();
```

When I debugged, both parameter return right things:

```
$request->id // return 2
$agent->id // return 1
```

[image]

Any idea?

Edit: Event model

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'file_id',
        'status',
        'description',
        'file_id',
        'agent_id'
    ];
    protected $hidden = ['updated_at'];
}
```

I figured out I get error 500 after use this:

```
Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->where('id', $request->id)->first()->remove();
```

> {message: "Call to undefined method App\Event::remove()", exception:
>   "BadMethodCallException",…}

Comment: Could you show the Event model?

Comment: @NguyenHungThai added

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? And when you say that  `Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->first();` returns true, do you mean `true` or true as it returns a item/model?

Comment: @KFoobar Latest version. yes it return items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `delete()` instead of `remove()` *!*

```
Event::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->where('id', $request->id)->first()->delete();
```

**[Delete()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models)** *vs.* **[Destroy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models)**

Comment: Thanks. Solved. What I missed? where should I use remove and where delete? whats different?

Comment: @tourtravel There are `destory()` and `(delete)` that's all *!* no `remove()`